# Internet Explorer 10 menu item shows focus outline unexpectedly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a CSS issue with my HTML menu. It appears only in IE. I have to make it compatible with IE10 and higher.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="categories-container">
    <ul class="categories">
        <li class="category item">
            <strong>
                <a class="text">Lorem ipsum 1</a>
            </strong>
        </li>
        <li class="category item">
            <strong>
                <a class="text">Lorem ipsum 2</a>
            </strong>
        </li>
        <li class="category item active">
            <strong>
                <a class="text">Lorem ipsum 3</a>
            </strong>
        </li>
        <li class="category item">
            <strong>
                <a class="text">Lorem ipsum 4</a>
            </strong>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

...and CSS:

```
.categories-container { width: 200px; margin: 30px; }
.categories {
    border-top: 1px dotted rgba(111, 111, 111, 1);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 37px 0 0 0;
}
.categories .category {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(111, 111, 111, 1);
}

.categories a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    color: #444;
}

.categories a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    background: rgba(220, 231, 235, 0.470588);
}

.categories .active a {
    color: #444;
    background: rgba(220, 231, 235, 1);;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I created a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9xTLb/) that demonstrates the issue.

Steps to reproduce:

- open the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9xTLb/)
- click on any item from menu
- if you are **not** on IE you will see this:

  > [image]
- if you **are** on IE you will see the border and underlined text:

  > [image]

How can I fix the border and the underlined text?

Comment: I just viewed your fiddle in IE10 and it looked exactly the same as it does in chrome, which is just like your first image...
EDIT: I added a href element to the a tags and now I see what you mean! I'll give it a crack and see what I can do.

Comment: @everydayghost Yes, I missed the hrefs. They are generated by the scripts. I am on Ubuntu, but I have installed Windows 7 with IE10 in the Virtual Box...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.categories a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none; /*removes text underline*/
    outline: none; /*removes dotted outline causing solid border*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xTLb/1/

Internet Explorer adds a dotted `outline` and an underline to links when you click them apparently, so that code does the trick :)